# Taking just an ouput on java

Tags: java, if-statement

This is a simple question i know but i got confused about this.
Im trying to get an output like this;

```
CourseG, CourseF and CourseE are available
```

But my output is getting like this;

```
CourseE is available
CourseG, CourseF, CourseE are available
CourseF and CourseE are available
```

My algorithm is;

```
if(a == 1){
    System.out.println("CourseE is available");
}
if(a ==1 && b == 1 && c == 1){
    System.out.println("CourseG, CourseF, CourseE are available");
}
if(a == 1 && b == 1){
    System.out.println("CourseF and CourseE are available");
}
else{
    System.out.println("no available Course");
}
```

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should check the largest first then use elseif statements ex.

```
if(a ==1 && b == 1 && c == 1){
     System.out.println("CourseG, CourseF, CourseE are available");
}
else if(a == 1 && b == 1){
     System.out.println("CourseF and CourseE are available");
}
else if(a == 1){
     System.out.println("CourseE is available");
}
else{
     System.out.println("no available Course");
}
```

Start with largest scope first and work your way in.

Comment: @Calaquessir , Note that the code won't work when Courses F and/or G are only avaliable(when b and/or c are 1)

Comment: Just add another else if statement if you want to account for F and G like @CoolGuy said.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you get that because each if is evaluated independently of the others (and a, b and c are 1). You should use if-else-if, if you want other behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Since your if statements are not followed by an else except the last time, each of the will be tested independently from the earlier ones.

Hence if `a == 1 && b == 1 && c == 1`, the first if statement will print `CourseE is available`, the second if will also be matched and print `CourseG, CourseF, CourseE are available` and finally the 3rd if will be matched, printing `CourseF and CourseE are available`.

If you just wanted to print exactly one of those case and stop the rest, you should do something like below (notice the `else if` in each line).

Notice that you also have to reorder your conditions starting from the most restricting case to the broadest condition:

```
if(a ==1 && b == 1 && c == 1){
    System.out.println("CourseG, CourseF, CourseE are available");
} else if(a ==1 && b == 1){
    System.out.println("CourseF and CourseE are available");
} else if(a == 1){
    System.out.println("CourseE is available");
} else{
    System.out.println("no available Course");
}
```

Comment: Nope. The logic in your code is broken. The `else if`s will never execute.

Comment: @CoolGuy: Thanks for the point. I will update the answer re. your comment.

Comment: Nope. Something is still wrong. Inspect the code carefully and fix it.

Answer (score -1):

**Based on your code, Try this:****

```
           `if(a == 1 && b != 1 && c != 1){
                System.out.println("CourseE is available");
            }
            else if(a !=1 && b == 1 && c != 1){
                System.out.println("CourseF is available");
            }
            else if(a !=1 && b != 1 && c == 1){
                System.out.println("CourseG is available");
            }
            else if(a == 1 && b == 1 && c !=1){
                System.out.println("CourseF and CourseE are available");
            }
            else if(a ==1 && b == 1 && c == 1){
                System.out.println("CourseE, CourseF, CourseG are available");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("no available Course");
            }`
```

**(You have to cover up the other cases following the same logic)**